# Is my explanation for the time complexity of this algorithm correct?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

The algorithm below returns the  [run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)  of a string s. [Problem from [here](https://binarysearch.com/problems/Run-Length-Encoding)].

```
string solve(string s) {
string answer;
int n = s.size();
int j = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n;) {
    char character = s[i];
    while (j < n && s[j] == character) {
        j++;
    }
    answer.append(to_string(j - i));
    answer.append(1, character);
    i = j;
}
return answer;
```

I believe that the time complexity of this algorithm is O(N), as at each iteration of the for loop, j is incremented by at least 1 and i is set to the modified j. This results in the algorithm above simply traversing the string.
Is my interpretation of the algorithm correct? 
Thank you.

Comment: That is correct.